# It's been a long time since I (went/have been) to Canada

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect

> It's been a long time since I **went** to Canada

Does the above sentence mean: *since* ***first*** or ***last*** *went to Canada*?

When you as a native speaker hear the above and below sentences, could you give me probabilities (by a sample of number of visits ) on the **difference** between those two sentences? This is of course if the first sentence has the meaning: ***first*** *went to Canada*

> It's been a long time since I **have been** to Canada

If you feel it is better to change ***a long time*** into e.g. ***5 years*** to make your answer clearer, then please do so.

Comment: If it were *"It's been a long time since **he** went to Canada",* it would likely mean that he went to Canada a long time ago and never came back. And in first person, if the speaker lives in Canada and is currently visiting another country, it would mean the same thing. In that case, it wouldn't be either the first time that he went to Canada or the last time he went to Canada, but the time that he moved there.

Comment: This is for *went* and it's clear if I understood you correctly, but what about *have been*?

Comment: For *have been*, it clearly refers to the last time. Similarly, if it were *"it's been a long time since I went to the gym,"* it would clearly mean *"**last** went"*. If it were *"it's been a long time since I went to college,"* it would probably mean *"**first** went"* (unless the speaker's talking about the entire period he was in college).

Comment: When you say clearly do you mean there is **no possibility** of going to the gym *after* that, and you consider the speaker is in error, or the possibility is negligible?

Comment: Sorry there is some racing conditions going over here in writing the comments!

Comment: Unless context gives some indication otherwise, I would say there is no possibility of the speaker having gone to the gym after that.

Comment: Just my observation, if he went back to the gym again then the time "he went to the gym" would mean this "latest went", which is still the "last went", by definition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> It's been a long time since I **went** to Canada.

To me, the above sentence is ideal only in cases where there is **only one** visit to Canada. In that sense, it would be **both** a first **and** the last (most recent) visit. That said, it's a valid construction in a situation where multiple visits had occurred, but in these cases I’d argue for:

> It's been a long time since I **have been** to Canada.

The way I figure it, the statement above has two main pieces of information:

1. I **have been** to Canada (at least once; possibly multiple times)
2. It has been a long time since then (since my last visit)

Broken down the same way, the first sentence has these two main pieces of information:

1. I **went** to Canada (most likely *just once*)
2. It's been a long time since then (since my one and only visit)

So it comes down to what you want to say. This might be the situation:

1. I **went** to Canada throughout my teens
2. It's been a long time since then

You could make an argument for either option in this case, but I maintain that the second sentence would more clearly indicate multiple visits.

Comment: I think you're quite right that in OP's exact context, the most *likely* distinction a native speaker would infer is that *went* implies there was only ever one visit (but only because *have been* very strongly implies there were multiple visits). In other contexts though, we might find a totally different distinction. For example, in *"It's been a long time since I went/have been hungry"*, the *went* version is more likely to mean *"I've had enough to eat for a long time now"* (but didn't always), where the alternative might be taken to mean *"I permanently lost my appetite a long time ago"*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I contemplated covering more, but quickly saw the possibilities spider out forever like cracks on the surface of a frozen lake. I suspect “went hungry” presents a special case, and I'm sure there are others. It seems like the technique of breaking down the information while determining the right verb for each statement would still work, though, even if there isn't a one-to-one correspondence between that example and OP's.