# What does "It has been five years since Peter worked here" mean?

Tags: meaning, perfect-constructions

Does it mean "Peter has been working here for five consecutive years"
 ?

Or does it mean "Peter hasn't worked here for five years. Somehow, he quit five
 years ago.?

What makes me confused is this following sentence in the same structure.

> It has been five years since Peter died here.

Does it mean "Peter has been dead here for five consecutive years" ?

Or does it mean "Peter hasn't died here for five years"?

Comment: The answer to this question might help a little: [It's been a long time since I (went/have been) to Canada](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/15226/)

Answer (score 1):

"It has been five years since Peter worked here" means that Peter stopped working here five years ago -- in other words, five years have elapsed since the last time he worked here.

"Peter has been working here for five consecutive years" is expressed also as "It has been five years since Peter *started* work*ing* here" or as "Peter has been working here for five years" or "Peter has been working here since five years ago (and continues to work here)".

It means the second option in OP's example in most cases.