# It's more than ten years since i last went, had gone or have gone to Alex

Tags: present-perfect, past-perfect, past-simple

It's more than ten years since i last (went _ had gone _ have gone) to Alex
Which one is correct and why

Comment: Is "Alex" a place? You don't use "go to" with a person.

Comment: Alexandria? See https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/15226/its-been-a-long-time-since-i-went-have-been-to-canada?rq=1 I would use _last went_ or _have last been_.